# Help Solving Trigonometry Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am having difficulties solving the following equation:

$$4\cos^2x=5-4\sin x$$

Hints on how to solve this equation would be helpful.

Comment: Try adding dollar signs around your equation, and back slashs before the cos and sin, to make the mathematics appear more visually appealing.  For the above, I changed the equation to  `$$4\cos^2x=5-4\sin x.$$`  This yields $$4\cos^2x=5-4\sin x.$$

Comment: Hint: Do you know a trig identity you could substitute in for $cos^{2}x$ that use $sin^{2}x$? Then simplify and solve the remaining equation.

Comment: Does the answer sinx=1/2 sound right to everyone?

Comment: ye check my solution

Answer (score 6):

Hint: You can use the identity: $$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2x =1.$$

Using substitution, you can then obtain a quadratic equation by letting $y = \sin x$.

Answer (score 4):

> $\cos^2(x) = 5-4 \sin(x)$

Move everything to the left hand side.

> $\cos^2(x)-5+4 \sin(x) = 0$

Write in terms of $sin(x)$ using the identity $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x)$:

> $4 \sin(x)-4-\sin^2(x) = 0$

Factor constant terms from the left hand side and write the remainder as a square:

> $-(\sin(x)-2)^2 = 0$

Multiply both sides by -1:

> $(\sin(x)-2)^2 = 0$

Take the square root of both sides:

> $\sin(x)-2 = 0$

Add 2 to both sides:
$\sin(x) = 2$

Your edited your post:

> $$4 cos^2(x) = 5-4 sin(x)$$

Subtract $5-4 sin(x)$ from both sides:

> $$4 cos^2(x)-5+4 sin(x) = 0$$

Using the identity $cos^2(x) = 1-sin^2(x):$

> $$4 sin(x)-1-4 sin^2(x) = 0$$

Factor constant terms from the left hand side and write the remainder as a square:

> $$-(2 sin(x)-1)^2 = 0$$

Multiply both sides by -1:

> $$(2 sin(x)-1)^2 = 0$$

Take the square root of both sides:

> $$2 sin(x)-1 = 0$$

Add 1 to both sides:

> $$2 sin(x) = 1$$

Divide both sides by 2:

> $$sin(x) = 1/2$$

Comment: +1, Interesting, I like that you provided a complete solution to a different problem than what the OP was asking.  This gives a strong hint.

Comment: It was not my intention :) Bilbo made a mistake. Now I gave him the correct solution.....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Substitute in $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, and solve the quadratic for $\sin x$.

Comment: I always forget to use factoring as an option to solve when solving trigonometry equations, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having difficulties solving the following equation:$${4\cos^2x=5-4\sin x}$$

First, substitute $4\cos^2(x)$ with $4\left(1 - \sin^2(x)\right)  = 4 - 4\sin^2(x).$ We are left with $4 - 4\sin^2(x)  = 5 - 4 \sin (x) .$ This can be rewritten as $-4\sin^2(x) + 4\sin(x) - 1 = 0.$

Observe that the equation can further be rewritten in the form $-4t^2 + 4t - 1 = 0$ where $t = \sin(x)$. Solve the quadratic equation for $t$ and then use $\sin(x) = t$ to solve for $x$.